# Joomla Backend Login Component

Tags: php, joomla

I'm currently trying to get a custom component working to log a user into the backend given their username and password.  I realize the inherent security problems this may present, but I would really like an answer to this problem I've been struggling with.  Here is the code in my controller.php:

```
function execute() {
    $credentials = array( 'username' => $this->username, 
        'password' => $this->password );
    $options = array();
    $options['group'] = 'Public Backend';
    $options['autoregister'] = false;
    $options['action'] = 'core.login.admin';
    $app =& JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
    $result = $app->login($credentials, $options);
    echo $result;
}
```

All the documentation that I've read says that this should work (even though it is not exactly kosher to perform admin tasks--like logging into the backend--from a non-admin context).  Any idea on what I'm not getting?

EDIT:  I forgot to mention which Joomla version I'm using: 2.5.14

Comment: if you want them to have backend access why not give them "Administrator" access and let the normal login system do the work, or create a group under Administrators and set the permissions to the different areas for that group and again let the login system do the login work?

Comment: I'm trying to get an external javascript application (webapp) to log the user in automatically, and to have them NOT go through the CMS-based login component.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pay attention to the Joomla authentication/login/authorization flow and user flow which are managed via user and authentication plugins.  From what you say it sounds like you will still be using the Joomla user table, is that right? So in that case the Joomla user plugin should work.

Assuming that is true you want to make an authentication plugin.  This plugin will be checked along with the joomla authentication plugin and any other authentication plugins you may have running (e.g. remember me/cookie login).

I don't totally understand what you are trying to do (and you haven't said what version of Joomla you are on, which makes a difference in this case), for example do you really want to login to the full back end or do you just want to show some screens the way the insert image plugin does? If on Joomla 3 you might want to look at the Google Summer of Code project for bringing some admin to the front end (called com_services for now). That student also has an http login plugin you could look at. https://github.com/Buddhima/Joomla-HttpLogin-plugin

Comment: Hi, 

I apologize for my brevity, this was the last thing I did before I left work.  I'm using Joomla 2.5.1, and I need to have not just the user authenticated, but to actually be fully logged in.  The reason for this is that the ACL for a CRM that I'm using only supports backend authentication, i.e. it checks for the cookie that the user gets when he/she logs into the backend.  As a result, I need a user to be fully logged in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: YOu need to authenticate before you login.
The User plugin handles actual logging in.
And if you are on 2.5.1 you need to update now.

Comment: I apologize, I meant 2.5.14